# Place dynamic DIVs in columns without vertical gaps between them?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, css-float

Got a series of quotes of varying length to fit in DIVs of fixed width but content determined height. I could individually position each DIV so it looked tidy and there were no vertical gaps. For example - http://www.zergnet.com/. I wondered if there was a CSS solution to problem, as I noted Zergnet uses inline styling and absolute positioning of every news teaser (which makes me think javascript is involved somewhere).

```
.testimonialBubble {
   position: relative;
   width:48%;
   margin: 8px 0;
   padding:0 2% 0 0;
   float: left;
}
```

The idea being no matter what volume of content is thrown (within reason) into the divs in the 2 col layout they'll fit together and fill spaces. At the moment if the 2nd element is longer than the 1st, when 3rd element kicks round under the 1st element there's a gap between the two caused by the 2nd elements height. Is there a CSS only solution or is it only achievable via javascript?

Many thanks for reading.

Comment: this probably isn't the answer you're looking for but you can accomplish a similar look pretty easily using bootstrap columns

Comment: If I understood your question clearly, you will need some javascript to do it, example http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Will your columns have a defined width?